# How to specify headers in zabbix web monitoring

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I need to monitor this curl command using zabbix.

curl -i -H "APPLICATIONKEY: kfkdiekd859662" -H "CONSUMERKEY: jdjdjd655222" -X POST https://test.api-test.com/confirm.

1. I have given the URL in url column.
2. I have been facing issue on how to specify the header in zabbix-web monitoring.

Under step tab.

Guide me, on how to specify header in zabbix.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify headers in the "Headers" field like so:

```
APPLICATIONKEY: kfkdiekd859662
```

See the [web scenario entry](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/web_monitoring) in the Zabbix manual for more detail.